# Invalid memory reference when opening a file that already exists

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, gfortran

I have some code that writes data to some files, I want to loop over this code to continue opening and writing to the files with different parameters. However, whenever I try this, once the files are created (after the first iteration of the loop) an error message occurs:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

The code would look a little like this:

```
program main
! premable here
DO a=1,10

call something(a, b, c)

END DO

contains

SUBROUTINE something(a, b, c)
!premable + data manipulation

open(12, FILE = 'file.name', STATUS='UNKNOWN')            ! the problem occurs here for 
                                                          ! the second iteration of the loop
                                                          ! in the main
DO i=.... ! general loop for extracting values from array
write(12, '(4F16.12)') b(:, i)
END DO
close(12)

END SUBROUTINE something


end program main
```

I have tried using `STATUS='OLD'` rather than `'UNKNOWN'` with empty files pre-created but this hasn't worked either (in fact with this the loop won't even complete the first iteration).

I am using GNU Fortran compiler with Windows and CODE::BLOCKS.

Comment: Please make a complete MWE (minimal working example) of it. Also try to compile your program with debug flags (like -g).

Comment: *The code would look a little like this:*  Please don't ask us to help track down bugs in what is, at best, approximately your code.  As it stands the invalid memory reference *might* be down to trying to write values of the undeclared array `b`.  But I suppose your response will be something like *Oh, actually, in my real code I have properly declared `b` ...* and to then edit your question.  Do as @Albert has suggested and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please also always use tag [tag:fortran]. Be sure to include it when revising the question with the [mcve]. Please take also the [tour] and read [ask].